# Mutex vs object issue

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

I was looking at java code for Collections.synhronizedMap().I found that it has below implementation.Now my question is 
*1) why are we using synchronized(mutex)* 
*2) what if we use synchronized(m)*

I understanding is that if we do synchronized(m) then also only one thread will be able to access the map.

```
static class SynchronizedMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1978198479659022715L;

    private final Map<K, V> m;

    final Object mutex;

    SynchronizedMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        m = map;
        mutex = this;
    }

    SynchronizedMap(Map<K, V> map, Object mutex) {
        m = map;
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }

    public void clear() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            m.clear();
        }
    }

    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return m.containsKey(key);
        }
    }

    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return m.containsValue(value);
        }
    }

    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return new SynchronizedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(m.entrySet(), mutex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return m.equals(object);
        }
    }
```

Edit:I want few clarifications which are also relevant to this question

1) Java’s **this** keyword is used to refer the current instance of the method on which it is used. So if i am putting mutex  on this keyword then does it mean that we will lock the current instance of the object or we will lock the current instance of thread? I would be grateful if somebody can explain a meaning of following statement in a more holistic  manner

```
mutex = this;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In either case only one thread can access the map contents at a time.

It is better style to have a mutex separate from the map. If the map passed in is having other threads synchronize on it then that doesn't affect this object. Separating the lock from the map lets the user specify the lock separately, so it allows the user to share a lock with something else.

This class was written in a way to let it use a lock from outside of itself, or to use itself as a lock. Why is not apparent since there's no context given, I assume there's a case where a coarse-grained locking is needed across this map and something else too.

I would prefer something like

```
private final Object mutex;

public SynchronizedMap(Map<K,V> map, Object mutex) {
    m = map;
    this.mutex = mutex;
}

public SynchronizedMap(Map<K,V> map) {
    this(map, new Object());
}
```

because this way there is at least the option of having a lock exclusively under the control of the object.

`this` here is referring to the SynchronizedMap object.

BTW, probably it doesn't use a private lock so that it can support client-side locking.

Comment: can you kindly describe it in a bit detail. I have seen this  in other classes also 
 final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock; 
 Also  can u suggest me any link to read to understand this fully. Kindly consider me layman regarding to this. It will help me as well as other people also who read this or try to understand the current concurrency scenario.

Comment: But look at the constructor!  `mutex = this`.  Yuk!  This implementation looks completely bassackward to me.  Not also that the "private" Map holds a reference to an object that was passed in to the constructor.  @AnilSharma I assume, since the whole class is declared `static` that it is an _inner_ class, and there probably is some reason why it was written that way, but taken out of context, it does not look like a shining example of good software design.

Comment: @Anil: I don't know what details you need, you could make your question more specific.

Comment: @jameslarge the "private" Maps holds a reference to a constructor argument because this is a view of the map. That's the intended behavior.

Comment: Sorry guys that guys from java does not need that much criticism. It is piece of code of java.util.Collections class. Basically i was looking at synchronization for Collections.synchronizedMap() method. Actually i did not want to paste the whole class of more than 1000 lines so pasted that part only.

Comment: @NathanHughes ...thanks mate, I just went through the client side locking, intrinsic locking and extrinsic locking from java concurrency in practice.

My question was  why should we need mutex there just use Synchronized(Map) becaue ultimately all the changes are going to happen on map.

Comment: @NathanHughes i have updated my question for one doubt which i had.

Comment: @Anil: this is the current object, not the current thread. no threads getting locked here.

Comment: @Magnamag, I'm not saying that anything is wrong with the overall design; I'm saying that `SynchronizedMap` (as shown above) is not an example of good design _if you take it out of context_.  Without the context, it _appears_ as if a private field of the class refers to a mutable object that _potentially_ could be modified by code in some other class.  That usually is bad design, but it could be OK if this class is hidden inside a module that never allows it to be used in that particular way.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out in the other answer: In general, and as a rule of thumb, it is preferable to have an explicit, dedicated, private "lock" object, instead of exposing the `synchronized` via public methods (In the latter case, *the object itself* will be the lock, and this may easily lead to deadlocks in certain situations)

However, the situation is a bit different here, because all this refers to a private inner class of the `Collections` class. Particularly, the main reason why there is an explicit `mutex` parameter  is that this mutex can be *shared* among several instances. The constructor

```
SynchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m, Object mutex)
```

is (only!) called in a subclass, namely in

```
SynchronizedSortedMap(SortedMap<K,V> m, Object mutex) {
    super(m, mutex);
    sm = m;
}
```

which just passes the given mutex through to the `SynchronizedMap`. This constructor, in turn, is called in the `subMap`, `tailMap` and `headMap` methods of the `SynchronizedSortedSet` class. For example:

```
public SortedMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey, K toKey) {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        return new SynchronizedSortedMap<>(
            sm.subMap(fromKey, toKey), mutex);
    }
}
```

Here, the mutex of the actual map is passed to the sub-maps as well.

So the effect here is that the *same* mutex is used for the map and its sub-maps. This would simply not possible if the synchronization in `SynchronizedMap` was synchronizing on the delegate map with `synchronized(m)`.